# VS 2017 test coverage seems to be measuring test code only

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, vstest

When I run code coverage analysis on my tests, i'm getting results for my actual test code, not the code being tested! check the results below:
[image]
The class I'm trying to actually test ("JobsDiscoveryServices") is not even mentioned there, only it's stub!!!

What am I doing wrong here?!?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running .NET Core tests, Add `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` to product csproj. Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#working-with-code-coverage, https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/800